# How to initialize RadioGroup

Tags: android, initialization, radio-group

I need to use RadioGroup in my app. But I can't initialize it in activity. What is the problem here?

[my screen for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofGXH.jpg)
[screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7yq3.jpg)

Comment: can you add the code that you have tried in place of the image

Comment: @NeelaySrivastava, why?) there are two lines in my image))

Answer (score 0):

hi did you try something like this,

```
RadioGroup mRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.amountcollecte_radiogroup);
mRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                int id = mRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                View radioButton = mRadioGroup.findViewById(id);
                if (radioButton.getId() == R.id.amountcollected_yes_radioButton) {


                } else if (radioButton.getId() == R.id.amountcollected_no_radioButton) {


                }
            }
        });
```

```
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/amountcollected_yes_radioButton"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:buttonTint="@color/black"
                android:checked="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Yes"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_large" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/amountcollected_no_radioButton"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:buttonTint="@color/black"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="No"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_large" />
        </RadioGroup>
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: it's didn't help me. Screen above.

Comment: What is problem ? Normally radio group just defined in this way only